# Using SVG's to cut fluid background graphics

Tags: css, wordpress, svg, widget, siteorigin

I'm using the following code within a newly created Site Origin widget in Wordpress.

```
<div class="svg-container row-svg row-separator" style="fill:<?php echo $sep_fill; ?>">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
            <path d="M0 0 L100 0 L100 2 L0 100 Z"></path>
        </svg>
    </div>
```

With the following CSS...

```
.row-separator {
margin-top: 0 !important;
margin-bottom: -175px !important;
height: 175px;
}
.svg-container {
height: 0;
position: relative;
z-index: 99;
}
svg:not(:root) {
overflow: hidden;
}
svg {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

And this nicely trims a background image like this:

[image: Image trimed with SVG code, background-color and transparency]

What I need to do is make is look like this at the foot, so a different path is required. Does anyone know how to specify such an SVG path with the Triangle centered?

Or is there an alternative method to achieve the same result??

Regards,

Bob

[image: Image needs triangle in specified path]

Help would be appreciated as I'm not sure whether this is possible??

regards,

Bob

Comment: If you want to learn how to write SVG `<path>` elements, then you will find there are numerous tutorials on the web.  Or you could read the SVG specification.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for the reply. I had searched for information on paths, unfortunately most don't start from scratch, but assume that you've already covered the basics, which was not the case. I have now acquired some reading material plus software to enable the creation of both simple and complex SVG's, so I'm now good to go.

Answer (score 0):

The basic SVG guide can be found at https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html

It's aimed at the beginner. For a more detailed look consider buying the following book:

SVG Essentials - J. David Eisenberg

Software for complex SVG outlines etc Inkscape.